# Finding the row associated with a text field that's been placed in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view consisting of lots of fields, divided into sections, with the fields sourced from a database. I wish to support in-place editing of the text in the fields, so I create a text field for each row and add it to me cell:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:myTextField];
```

I give the text field a fixed tag so that I can easily configure the cell:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Item *item = [self itemWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1000];
    textField.text = item.name;
}
```

When the text field has been edited I need to update the database. I can set up a delegate on the text field to respond to the end of the editing, but I somehow have to find out which indexPath has been edited so that I can update the database appropriately.

How can I do this?

I suppose I could maintain a tag->IndexPath mapping that get's updated each time I configure a cell, but that feels like overkill. Is my tired brain missing the obvious?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my brain started working:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)textField.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    Item *item = [self itemWithIndexPath:indexPath];
    item.name = textField.text;
}
```